# Django queryset return data if any condition matches and break

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model which stores player details.

```
class Player(models.Model):
    """
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_legth=10, unique=True)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
```

Now I want to filter `Player` model data by passing a string value which I will match with all 3 columns(name, team and type).

I want to write a query in django ORM which will give results when any on 3 condition will match and queryset will stop checking further if any condition match.

**My Try :**

```
from operator import __or__
q = Q(name=input), Q(team=input), Q(type=input)
slots = slots.get(reduce(__or__, q))
```

But above example is not working fine. It is returning me multiobject queryset.

**EDIT**

**Example :**

```
>>> from base_data.models.booking import Player
>>> Player.objects.create(name='test', team=1, type=2)
<Player: Player object>
>>> Player.objects.create(name=3, team='test', type=2)
<Player: Player object>
>>> Player.objects.create(name=5, team=6, type='test')
<Player: Player object>
>>> 
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> val = 'test'
>>> Player.objects.filter(Q(name=val))
[<Player: Player object>]
>>> Player.objects.filter(Q(name=val) | Q(team=val) | Q(type=val))
[<Player: Player object>, <Player: Player object>, <Player: Player object>]
>>> # above result should return me first player model instance when name==val.
>>># it should break and should not check next conditions.
```

**I am using sqlite3.**

**Solution for now :**

```
   out =  Player.objects.filter(name=input) or Player.objects.filter(team=input) or Player.objects.filter(type=input)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) in your query.

Comment: It is not returning me duplicates.

Comment: @Prashant. Can you show the real and expected output ?

Comment: If you want only first row matching query, then you can use limit [:1].

Answer (score 0):

Checking with break if first condition is met can be done using this way, regardless the DB hits and regardless the messy code.

```
query_string = "test"

players = Player.objects.filter(name=query_string)

if players.count() == 0:
    players = Player.objects.filter(team=query_string)

if players.count() == 0:
    players = Player.objects.filter(type=query_string)

if players.count() == 0:
    # you don't have results
else:
    # you have results
```

---

Moreover, think about it from DB prospective. You will never be able to write one SQL query that match your condition!

```
 SELECT * FROM players where name = "test" OR type = "test" or team = "test"
```

This will get the same results you get because it's an OR condition.

**Django can never know and will never be able to understand if the first condition is met or not without at least hitting the database.**

Comment: Still having same issue which was with my query.

Comment: @PrashantGaur what kind of issues? the code will perform a simple OR condition on the three columns.

Comment: @PrashantGaur I actually couldn't understand your condition. Are you checking for names then if empty check in teams then if empty check in types? otherwise stop if one is found at any stage?

Comment: i want to stop  if one is found at any stage and return result queryset.

Comment: Hey I am trying to get away from these checks , I have already done my work with the use of above kind of checks.I am trying to learn that if we can stop checking if resultset is found at any stage.

Comment: This will end up in multiple db queries. Worst case is three queries when no match found. That can impact performance.

Comment: We can do this by using python or operator.
out =  Player.objects.filter(name=input) or Player.objects.filter(team=input) or Player.objects.filter(type=input)

Comment: @RajeshKaushik You will never be able to determine if the condition is true or not without hitting the database. The trigger to stop checking can not be done without hitting the database each time. the problem is the question not the solution. I think he want to increase the performance by stopping however, this cause a lot of damages.

Comment: @Othman but using python's or operator can help us to reduce database hits because it will go to second case when First will be false.

Comment: @PrashantGaur if you have all the data with you in python, then YES!. if you don't then you have to go and check if it's "False" or not right?